# In python os.chdir() is not working with relative path

Tags: python

I want to change the working directory in python using os.chdir() from the current project folder to an existing folder in the project folder but it shows a file not found error.

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir("../NewDirectory/") #Error here

print(os.getcwd())
```

I expected an output:

```
C:\Users\John Doe\PycharmProjects\untitled
C:\Users\John Doe\PycharmProjects\untitled\NewDirectory
```

But I got the result:

```
C:\Users\John Doe\PycharmProjects\untitled

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/John Doe/PycharmProjects/untitled/miketest.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.chdir("../NewDirectory/")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '../NewDirectory/'
```

Comment: The "NewDirectory" folder exists and is in the "untitled" folder

Comment: .. stands for the previous directory

Comment: `../` means "go up 1 folder"... if you want to go to `untitled\NewDirectory`, you need `os.chdir('NewDirectory')`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Post it as an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say that `NewDirectory` exists inside `untitled` which is the current directory.

Then your relative path `../NewDirectory` is incorrect because it attempts to find `NewDirectory` inside the *parent* of the current directory. That is, it attemps to find `NewDirectory` inside `PycharmProjects`; which doesn't exist.

Replacing your call with `os.chdir("NewDirectory")` should work as expected. 
`"NewDirectory"` by itself is a relative path and refers to a directory inside the current one.

If you want to make it more explicit, you can write it as `os.chdir("./NewDirectory")`, which emphasises the fact that `NewDirectory` is located inside the current directory (`.`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it was a simple doubt, really appreciate you taking the time.